# Low-voltage wireless switch

Tags: home-electronics, internet-of-things

I am searching for an alternative to the popular *Sonoff Basic* WiFi switch, which satisfies the following requirements:

- Low voltage: **5V or 12V DC** (input and output)
- Standardized protocol: **WiFi, Bluetooth or Z-Wave** preferred
- **CE certification**